# Managing form validation in react - Trying to relegate validation to subcomponents

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I have a form in react, which is huge. It has around 80 fields and when checking/unchecking some checkbox, fields are mounted or unmounted.

I've got one problem when I want to warn of an error in one of this fields.

The structure of this form is something like this:

```js
//parentNode.js
render: function() {
  if(this.refs.tab1 && this.refs.tab1.isError()) var tab1icon = <img src="my.."/>
  if(this.refs.tab2 && this.refs.tab2.isError()) var tab2icon = <img src="my.."/>
  if(this.refs.tab3 && this.refs.tab3.isError()) var tab3icon = <img src="my.."/>

  return(
    <div>
      <tab1>
        {tab1icon}
        <subform ref="tab1" data={this.state.form.tab1}/>
      </tab1>
      <tab2>
        {tab2icon}
        <subform ref="tab2" data={this.state.form.tab2}/>
      </tab2>
      <tab3>
        {tab3icon}
        <subform ref="tab3" data={this.state.form.tab3}/>
      </tab3>
    </div>
  );
},


//middleNode.js

isError: function() {
  for (field in this.refs) {
     //... Filter prototype properties.
     if(this.refs[field].isError()) return true;
  }
  return false;
}


//leafNode.js

isError: function() {
  //Validate this.refs.myLeafNode.getValue()
}
```

The problem here is that, I'm checking for errors before this tabs are re-rendered so if some fields are going to be unmounted isError is going to validate them. Suppose one of those fields contains a non-valid value, after unmounting it this value is no-longer important, but with this solution the Error Icon will be shown.

So, which is the best way of implementing this kind of validation? 
I try to relegate the responsability of managing each subform to its react component because as I said this form is very complex and differnt subforms have different rules.